# Is GZIPOutputStream known to loose data during compression?

Tags: java, gzipoutputstream

I have a very strange issue with [GZIPOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) when compressing an array of doubles. At the 57th element, I get a small discrepancy when I reload the data:

```
57 > 3.003727492141554E7 3.0037273913440887E7
1900: false
57 > -6.110783629228158E7 -6.110783629076558E7
2000: false
```

1900 and 2000 are two different set of doubles. The left value is the original value.

When I use a simple [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) without GZIP, I don't get the issue. Why? Is GZIP output stream known to loose information?

**EDIT**

Here is how I read and write the data:

```
public static final double[] coefficients = new double[1161289];

...

public static void dump(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    OutputStream os = FileUtils.zipContent(f);

    byte[] ba = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer BF = ByteBuffer.wrap(ba);
    BF.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    for (int i=0;i<coefficients.length;i++) {
        BF.putDouble(0, coefficients[i]);
        os.write(ba,0,8);
    }

    os.close();

}

public static void load(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    InputStream is = FileUtils.readZippedContent(f);

    byte[] ba = new byte[8];
    final ByteBuffer BF = ByteBuffer.wrap(ba);
    BF.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    for (int i=0;i<coefficients.length;i++) {
        is.read(ba,0,8);
        coefficients[i] = BF.getDouble(0);
    }

}

...

public static GZIPOutputStream zipContent(File f)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    return new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

}

public static GZIPInputStream readZippedContent(File f)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    return new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

}
```

Comment: How, **exactly,** are you writing the array of doubles to the output stream?

Comment: how are you serializing the doubles?

Comment: Why don't you use DataOutputStream ?

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE!!! Where do you invoke the load/dumpe methods? Where do you add data to the array? Where is the FileUtils class?

Comment: @leonbloy I tried using DataOutputStream and the issue is solved. Create an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717165/779408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip is lossless compression. any missing data would have to be accounted for by some other problem.

if the 57th element is the final element, I'd suspect failure to close the output file before re-opening for reading.

Comment: 57th element is not the final element.

Comment: I have changed my routine to use DataOutputStream instead and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 4):

what makes you think that: `is.read(ba,0,8);` returns `8` *always*?

In short: the reading routine is bogus.

Comment: Because what I put in this file is a multiple of 8

Comment: @JVerstry, you'd be better off reading the doc of InputStream#read... and then I know for a fact zip streams may not return full amount of data when there are leftover bytes in their internal window.

Comment: This could explain my issue indeed.

Comment: @JVerstry, yes, always, i mean always check the returned value of `read(...)` function. You are dealing w/ IO, the stream can be corrupter/cut, so you must be prepared handling errors.