# Decompressing GZIP

Tags: java, android, gzip

I would like to know what I'm supposed to do in the case of a gzip-encoded response. this is the method handling my responses :

```
private InputStream getResultStream(Response response) throws IOException
{
    InputStream resultStream = null;
    if(response != null)
    {
        String encoding = response.getHeader("Content-Encoding");
        if((encoding != null) && (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")))
        {
            // What to do here ?
            Log.d("Stream :", "Read GZIP");

        } else if ((encoding != null) && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("deflate")) {
            resultStream = new InflaterInputStream(response.getStream(), new Inflater(true));
            Log.d("Stream :", "Read Deflated.");
        } else {
            resultStream = response.getStream();
            Log.d("Stream :","Read Normal.");
        }       
    }

    return resultStream;
}
```

How do I approach this ?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717165/779408. A compress and decompress method is represented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not had a chance to test this.

According to what [Android’s HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) blog post says if you are on Android 2.3+, then `HttpURLConnection` can do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your stream in a [`GZIPInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) and read from that.

```
resultStream = new GZIPInputStream(resultStream);
//proceed reading as usual
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how to read a gziped stream, just wrap your inputstream with a [GZIPInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html)

```
 InputStream is = ...
 GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
 try {
     // Reading from 'zis' gets you the uncompressed bytes...
     processStream(zis);
 } finally {
     zis.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
resultStream = new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(response.getStream());
```

Comment: Tried it which caused the following exception :

06-25 15:00:06.465: W/System.err(15873): java.io.IOException: stream closed
06-25 15:00:06.465: W/System.err(15873):  at libcore.net.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:68)
06-25 15:00:06.465: W/System.err(15873):  at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:41)