# How can i improve performance of calling web services in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I developed an android application using web services. Here i am calling web services to get data from server and showed in my application views. Application is working fine but calling web services is gave me performance issues. It will take more time to get data.

I am using the below code to call api and used handler to parse the data. And my result is in XML format. I am using SAX parser to parse data. I don't know why the application is very slow to get data and parse. Please provide me good performance service hint for me.

Here is my api calling code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity entity = null;         
        entity = new StringEntity(xmlRequest, HTTP.UTF_8);      
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        httppost.setEntity(se);
    BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
    InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

I am converting this input stream to string builder and parsing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe your webservice response is large. if it is large compress its data.

Comment: Try to investigate more, check if the delay is from the Webservice or from the parsing itself. IF from the webservice it could be a network issue, mayble your webservice needs caching or more optimization

Comment: Thanks for your response @breceivemail . Yes may be it is large.could you please hit how zip data is helpfull and what is the process

Comment: look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717165/779408).

Comment: @Hassan Mokdad. No it is working fast in iphone device

Comment: if your data is large, consider paging it

Comment: mmm, if it works fast on the IPhone device, The the webservice is ok, even compressing the data won't help you much, Check the parsing code on your android side

Comment: @nizk2.what is paging how can we use. please suggest me