# sending large JSON data from android to php server can I compress?

Tags: json, gzip, getjson, compression

i am sending large datasets in JSON format from my android device to my server (using PHP). I want to keep bandwidth costs down. I am wondering:
should I gzip compress the JSON data server side before sending the data?
is there a javascript gzip uncompression library in php side and what i do in android side?

Comment: following stackoverflow Question may help you <br>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717165/how-can-i-zip-and-unzip-a-string-using-gzipoutputstream-that-is-compatible-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compress your JSON output in this way from PHP server.

```
echo gzencode(json_encode($data));
```

And for android side you can use `"gzip decoder"`

Answer (score 3):

You should compress your output JSON, but you can let your php sever side script do it for you. If you use a standard compression on HTTP level the client will decompress that automatically

http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=104

If you want to send JSON data single form than use following way

```
echo gzencode(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
echo gzencode(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=android+gzip+decode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=bHnhVJjPCOTV8geAjoCAAg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717165/how-can-i-zip-and-unzip-a-string-using-gzipoutputstream-that-is-compatible-with

Answer (score -1):

You can use below for compress `json`

```
print_r(gzcompress($data));
```