# Adding GZIP encoding results in MalformedJsonException

Tags: android, performance, gzip, jsonreader

I added this header in my base request: "Accept-encoding", "gzip"

This now results in a MalformedJsonException urging me to use JsonReader.setLenient(true)

I've modified my code to this to support that:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(myStringReader with json string));
jsonReader.setLenient(true);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject object = parser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();
```

I'm still getting the same error, thoughts anyone?

Comment: You can uncompress the `gzip` String using `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

Couple things -

1. If you're setting the GZIP header, that tells the server you're contacting that you're able to unzip a gzip'd response. Likely you're getting back the compressed response, and trying to parse it as json - you need to decompress it first.
2. If you're using `HttpUrlConnection`, it will automatically set the gzip header *and* unzip it for you. You can confirm this by proxying your app and looking at the http requests it makes.
3. A funny thing about `HttpUrlConnection` is that while it will set the gzip header and decompress for you, *if you set the gzip headers yourself, it will not*. It then will rely on you to decompressed it.

So in short, either don't set the header at all and rely on `HttpUrlConnection` to do it all for you, or you must decompress the response using the `GZIPInputStream` class prior to your json code, see this answer for an in-depth explanation:

[How can I Zip and Unzip a string using GZIPOutputStream that is compatible with .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717165/how-can-i-zip-and-unzip-a-string-using-gzipoutputstream-that-is-compatible-with)